# Getting an “Operation not permitted” error when running commands after to SSHing from another machine to macOS

Tags: bash, ssh, mac, terminal

I try to SSH from MacBook A to another iMac (iMac B) with two external drives connected to it. SSH is successful but I cannot perform the `ls` and `touch` commands.

Although I set the full disk access to `terminal`, `ls`, `touch` commands, and even `sshd`, I cannot use it and it is returned to Operation not permitted.

This error happened when I try to use those commands in the Desktop folder or external drive but nothing with the interactive terminal on the iMac B.

Even the root account cannot perform this command, so it should have a higher level account than the root, is that?

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Forget about using touch for a little while (that requires write access), focus on just using `ls`.  On Mac B (directly logged in as "duy"?), can you `ls` other directories, like your homedir?  And on Mac B (still directly logged), can you `ls /Volumes/DuyData2`?  It's not clear from your question if that works on Mac B (directly logged in) or if you get the same errors as you get over SSH.  Again, focus on `ls` for now, then solve `touch` later.

Comment: hi @jimtut
Actually interactively (directly working on iMac B), I can perform all of those things (ls Desktop folder and /Volume/DuyData2 also).
I can ls the homedir and / dir as well

Comment: Ok, then from Mac A, you are prevented from doing those operations on Mac B, when connecting over SSH. I don’t have an answer, just trying to help you debug. I like your idea to grant Full Disk Access to all those processes, I think that’s the right idea. Can you open the Console app on Mac B, observe the “regular” types of messages (there’s usually a steady stream of regular stuff in there), then try the SSH and LS from Mac A?  If you can find which app/process does not have permission, maybe you can grant that one Full Disk Access.

Comment: @jimtut
still fail to find the answer.

Comment: Which MacOS version? Newer versions increasingly lock the system down, in non-unix ways, so even root makes no difference. For reference, `ssh` between Macs worked out of the box for on Mojave.

Comment: I just tried this out in a similar config: Mac A (Mac running 11.1) to Mac B (M1 Mac mini running 11.1), and it worked fine.  From Mac A, I could SSH to Mac B, `cd` to various places, including attached USB drives and iCloud directories.  I could 'ls` and 'touch` files, no errors.  You should check the Console on Mac B for errors, and maybe also try with a new user on Mac B, first insuring that the user can do all those things locally on Mac B, and then try again from Mac A (`ssh newuser@macb.lan`).

Comment: @jimtut Mac B is Big Sur version

Comment: @dirkt I totally agree. A bit strange

Answer (score 23):

Try add `sshd-keygen-wrapper` in the Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access

I encountered the same and solved by above.

Comment: `/usr/libexec/sshd-keygen-wrapper` is the path to the binary to be added, it works.

Comment: This can also be done by going to System Preferences --> Sharing --> Remote Login --> checking the box for "Allow full disk access for remote users". Checking this box will automatically check the `sshd-keygen-wrapper` box mentioned above.

Comment: @MattPopovich this is objectively a better answer. Why put it only as a comment?

Comment: From sharing in the system preference just give allow full disk access for the remote user

Comment: @MattPopovich For me, I used Migration Assistant to move everything between mac minis, and while "Allow full disk access for remote users" was checked in Remote Login, the switch was not on for `sshd-keygen-wrapper`, I had to manually turn it on. So this answer worked better for me in my situation!

Answer (score 10):

I confirm the popular above comment made by @MattPopovich. Still, this answer has yet to be posted outside comments. The original question can be resolved with *System Preferences --> Sharing --> Remote Login --> checking the box for "Allow full disk access for remote users"*. The default value is checked, so the problem most likely only happens if someone un-checks that option.

[image: MacOs_SystemPrefs_Sharing_RemoteLogin dialog]

Comment: Can also confirm this works now that the System Settings re-write has overtaken System Preferences: enabling Sharing... Remote LoginA and then clicking the little i in a circle to enable Allow full disk access for remote users - you likely want to enable it only for users who are Administrators

Comment: Thanks, @glenschler! I probably should have posted it as an answer but I thought it was quite similar to the original answer and was waiting for the community to think it was worth its own answer... then I forgot about it! Glad it was helpful.